# XY chart labels are exceeding the chart boundry

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

When I have some values in the XY chart, some column label locations' are exceeding the boundary of the chart, like in the image, how can I suppress that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by either increasing `paddingRight` of the whole chart or by setting `axis.maxLabelPosition = 0.98` which would result last label to be hidden.

Comment: Can also use `chart.paddingRight` to increase right margin.